# How to handle original .php files on a site with userfriendly url's (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I have this site which uses userfriendly URL's. I'm new to this and do not have so much expirence so far. I have everything working for now :-)

E.g. `list.php?t=new` is rewritten to `new-products/`

However to day I could see that googlebot tried to index a page based on the original URL (`list.php?t=new&ipp=25`).

Should I put logic in my .htaccess file to block access to all .php files? Or how is this to be handled?

I don't know where where GoogleBot found this URL. It's not on the site as it's active today. Maybe from cache or something...

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 301 redirect to tell search engines (and other visitors) the new locations.

Comment: So as the same time I rewrite from `new-products` to `list.php?t=new` using `RewriteRule`, I should also redirect `list.php?t=new` to `new-products`? Using? Isn't this a loop?

Comment: No, because you would have one rule that redirects the old style URL to the new style URL; then when .htaccess encounters the new style URL it will map it to the PHP script as you have directed it to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a rule that matches against the actual request instead of the URI (which could cause redirect looping). Something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /list\.php\?t=new&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /new-products/?%1 [L,R=301]
```

In this case, a request for `/list.php?t=new&ipp=25` will get redirected to `/new-products/?ipp=25`.

Comment: I simply cannot get this to work... I suspect the regex in middle of the `RewriteCond` to be wrong. I'll try again tomorrow :S

Comment: @ThomasK.Nielsen All the rules and patterns assume that both `list.php` and `new-products` are in the document root, since you've never mentioned anything being in other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are simpler ways, you can specify robots.txt not to index your php pages, and you can add canonical tag to the head to specify the version to be indexed.